# Is there a possibility to sort columns with tag attributes?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm using dataTables 1.8.2. And I need to sort some columns with the data which can't be sorted on a normal basis. Is there a way to sort columns according to the value of some attribute of the table element? I'm making a table and then applying dataTables, so I can compose a value attribute of a normal int like this:

```
<td value="10">data1</td>
<td value="9">data2</td>
```

I know that there is a way to prepare your own sorting functions, this way seems simpler for me.

Comment: Useful answer with an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863793/datatables-sorting-html-table-on-the-basis-of-td-attribute-value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please see these examples http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting